# Text resolution suddenly varies widely across multiple monitors and is not correctly scaling amongst window resolutions on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a 64 bit HP Spectre x360 Convertible 14-ea0xxx running Windows 10. It's primarily a work laptop and hasn't had any issues for the year so I've been using it, but seemingly out of nowhere a few weeks ago it started displaying text in the toolbars of various applications extremely small, while other text is displayed normally. The variance of the text rules out simply using Ctrl + Scroll Wheel (or + and -) to resize the windows, and it makes me think that it's not even a settings issue. I've included several images to illustrate the issue through its occurrence in various applications, including Google Chrome and ArcGIS Pro which we use heavily for work. I tried to highlight the issues in red pen.
[Within ArcGIS Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqLOK.jpg)

[Within Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaHp1.png)

In addition, I have tried compensating for the small text by increasing the text size to 200%, but it hasn't helped particularly well. I also noticed in the display settings that the "recommended resolution" is now 3000 x 2000, instead of the usual 1920 x 1080. As far as I know, the two external monitors I've been using have always used 1920 x 1080 so this was strange.

[My display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmMLU.png)

As mentioned, this is so bizarre that it doesn't even seem like a settings issue and makes me wonder if it's a driver issue, although I have made sure all my drivers are completely up to date. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try and toggle the "Fix scaling for apps" in the advanced scaling settings? It looks like chrome in your screenshot is not scaling the text correctly though - have you already restarted the PC? Those laptops do come with a 3000x2000 display (for the built-in screen at least). Also take a look in Settings > Ease of Access > Vision > Display, and there are some additional options for text size and window scaling that might fix the issue if you reset/wiggle them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've tried restarting everything several times but to no avail. Nothing in the Display settings seems to fix this issue without creating another issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason editing and creating a custom resolution and then reverting it back to the default resolution fixed the issue!